# How can I prove this inequality? [...]

Tags: inequality, integers

$3^{n+m}+n^2+m^2>2^{n+m+2}-2n(m+2)-4(m+1)$ where $n,m \ge 1$ and are integres.

I haven't written a proof with two variables yet so this caught me off-guard. I would appreciate any hints and suggestions! Or even some links to questions that deal with a similar proof.

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be lots of extraneous terms. It suffices to prove that $3^{n+m}>2^{n+m+2}$ for large $n,m$ and deal with the small cases more carefully

Comment: *Hint.* You can see that $n^2+m^2+2n(m+2)+4(m+1)=n^2+2n(m+2)+(m+2)^2=(n+m+2)^2$. It suffices to show that $3^{n+m}+(n+m+2)^2>2^{n+m+2}$. You may regard $t:=m+n$ and show the inequality $3^t+(t+2)^2>2^{t+2}$ by induction on $t$.

Comment: Just an idea: $n^2 + m^2 > 2^{n+m+2} - 2nm - 4n - 4m -4 - 3^{n+m}$ is equivalent to $(n+m)^2 > 2^{n+m+2} - 3^{n+m} - 4(n+m) - 4$. Now put $k = n+m$ so the inequality simplifies to $k^2 > 2^{k + 2} - 3^k - 4k - 4$, which could be simplified further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps by fixing first one term than the other.  So to do it by induction.

Base case: $n = m = 1$

$3^{n+m} +n^2 +m^2 = 3^2+1+1 =11$ and $2^{m+n+2} -2n(m+2) -4(m+1)= 2^4 - 2*6-4*2= 16-12-8=- 4$

First induction step:  Assume it is true for a specific $n$ and $m$.  Prove it is true for $n$ and $m+1$.

$3^{n+(m+1)} + n^2 + (m+1)^2 = 3^{n+m}\cdot 3 + n^2 + m^2 + 2m + 1 = [3^{n+m} + n^2 + m^2] + [2\cdot 3^{n+m} + 2m + 1]$

while $2^{(m+1) + n+2} -2n((m+1)+2) - 4((m+1)+1)=2\cdot 2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) - 2n -4(m+1) - 4= [2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) -4(m+1)]+[2^{m+n+2}- 2n-4]$

Now $3^{n+m} + n^2 + m^2 > 2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) -4(m+1)$ and $2\cdot 3^{n+m} + 2m + 1> 2^{m+n+2}- 2n-4$ so

$3^{n+(m+1)} + n^2 + (m+1)^2>2^{(m+1) + n+2} -2n((m+1)+2) - 4((m+1)+1)$.

.....

The base case and that first induction step proves our first result:

Result 1: For $n = 1$ and $m \in \mathbb N$ then $3^{n+m} +n^2 +m^2 > 2^{m+n+2} -2n(m+2) -4(m+1)$.

Now we do a second induction step: Is we assume it is true for a specific $m$ and $n$ prove it is true for $m$ and $n+1$.

$3^{(n+1)+m+1} + (n+1)^2 + (m+1)^2 = 3^{n+m}\cdot 3 + n^2 +2n + 1+ m^2= [3^{n+m} + n^2 + m^2] + [2\cdot 3^{n+m} + 2n + 1]$

while $2^{n + (n+1)+2} -2(n+1)(m+2) - 4(m+1)=2\cdot 2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) - 2(m+2) -4(m+1)= [2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) -4(m+1)]+[2^{m+n+2}-2(m+2)]$

Now $3^{n+m} + n^2 + m^2 > 2^{m+n+2}- 2n(m+2) -4(m+1)$ and $2\cdot 3^{n+m} + 2n + 1> 2^{m+n+2}-2(m+2)$ so

That proves the second induction step.

Combine that with result 1) we have the result holds for any $n,m$